# Posting songs with SoundCloud PHP API and CURLFile

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, soundcloud

First time posting on StackOverflow.

I'm building an application that uses the SoundClound PHP API. Basically, I want to authenticate and upload songs.

I've been working in my local server, and when I try to upload, I get the following error:

```
Message: curl_setopt_array(): The usage of the @filename API for file uploading is deprecated. Please use the CURLFile class instead
```

I'm using CodeIgniter but the CI Library for SoundCloud is too old, so i'm doing things on my own.

I don't have any experience with CURL, I only know how to use it for basic stuff. What I can see by some google search and the message is that the usage of the '@' for the filename is deprecated, but I can't find where to use the CURLFile in the SoundCloud API.

Here's my upload code:

```
    $sc_token = $this->accounts->refresh(1);
    $client = new Services_Soundcloud(SC_CLIENT_ID,SC_CLIENT_SECRET);
    $client->setAccessToken($sc_token);

    $track_path = '@/_uploads/' . $track_name;

    // upload audio file
    $track = json_decode($client->post('tracks', array(
        'track[title]' => $p['title'],
        'track[tags]' => 'funk rio pancadao mc dj',
        'track[asset_data]' => $track_path
    )));
```

Best regards!

Comment: Have you give a look to my library? have an helper method to upload tracks to soundcloud. if you have time https://github.com/njasm/soundcloud it fixes that issue.

Comment: Thanks! I'm checking it out now. Let's see how it goes ;)

Comment: njasm, I'm unable to make it work :( ----------

I'm including the "autoload.php" file, but it keeps saying: -----------

Fatal error: Class 'Soundcloud' not found in /Library/WebServer/Documents/funkeiros/application/models/accounts.php on line 11
  -------
I didn't install using Composer.. I just downloaded the file and put in my server.

Comment: the library is not just one file, you have to download the entire folder Soundcloud and sub-folders. don't change the folders sturcture. include in your app the file autoload.php from the lib before using any of the classes. check the README in the github page. let me now if you made it.